# Unable to connect to Ubuntu 14.04 guest from Ubuntu 14.04 host in VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, ssh

I was trying ssh hands-on and was trying to connect to a Ubuntu guest 14.04 on VirtualBox from a Ubuntu 14.04 host. I had opened port 22 in both the endpoints and tried the `ssh` command. I got a "no route to host" message. May I know how to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have set up networking in Virtualbox between the host and the guest. The two most common set-ups are `NAT` or `Bridged`.

In the NAT (Network Address Translation) case you will have to set up port forwarding to access the guest from your host. AFAIK, this is the default for Virtualbox and you will likely be using that if you have not changed the network settings when you creted the VM (Virtual Machine).

Setting up Port Forwarding is not difficult, but how it works is more difficult to understand than using `Bridged`. In NAT mode, the guest uses the IP address of the host.

The easiest is to use `Bridged`. You have to set this up when the virtual machine is turned off. Go to the `Network` tab in Virtualbox for the VM and set the `Attached to:` field to 'Bridged Adapter' and start the VM.

In Bridged mode the VM gets its own IP address on your network (via DHCP).

After the VM has started, log in and give the command `ifconfig` in a terminal window. This should give you the IP address of the guest machine.
You can then `SSH` from your host to the guest: `ssh <username>@<guest IP>`.

Alternatively, after the VM has started, log in give the command `hostname` in a terminal window. This should give you the hostname of the guest machine.
You can then `SSH` from your host to the guest: `ssh <username>@<hostname>`.

You can omit `username@` if you want to `ssh` using the same username as on your host.

Comment: If bridge is not possible, one can also create an additional host-only interface for communication between the guest and the host, in addition to a NAT one for Internet access.